# Query records belonging to the logged in user

Tags: php, mysql

I've written the below query:

At the moment this pulls back everything from the MarketingCampaigns table, regardless of which user created the record.

I need to be able to return the result, which counts only the records created by that user.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "doimkr943k3f";
$dbname = "crm4";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

                $sql = "SELECT format(count(id),0) as id12 FROM MarketingCampaigns";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result2->fetch_assoc();
echo $row["id12"];


?>
```

The below is a query I can see has been 'auto-generated' by the tool I use, which checks which fields the user should see in table view. I'm just really unsure how to convert this into the simple, single value SQL queries I have above.

```
// mm: build the query based on current member's permissions
    $DisplayRecords = $_REQUEST['DisplayRecords'];
    if(!in_array($DisplayRecords, array('user', 'group'))){ $DisplayRecords = 'all'; }
    if($perm[2]==1 || ($perm[2]>1 && $DisplayRecords=='user' && !$_REQUEST['NoFilter_x'])){ // view owner only
        $x->QueryFrom.=', membership_userrecords';
        $x->QueryWhere="where `Complaints`.`id`=membership_userrecords.pkValue and membership_userrecords.tableName='Complaints' and lcase(membership_userrecords.memberID)='".getLoggedMemberID()."'";
    }elseif($perm[2]==2 || ($perm[2]>2 && $DisplayRecords=='group' && !$_REQUEST['NoFilter_x'])){ // view group only
        $x->QueryFrom.=', membership_userrecords';
        $x->QueryWhere="where `Complaints`.`id`=membership_userrecords.pkValue and membership_userrecords.tableName='Complaints' and membership_userrecords.groupID='".getLoggedGroupID()."'";
    }elseif($perm[2]==3){ // view all
        // no further action
    }elseif($perm[2]==0){ // view none
        $x->QueryFields = array("Not enough permissions" => "NEP");
        $x->QueryFrom = '`Complaints`';
        $x->QueryWhere = '';
        $x->DefaultSortField = '';
    }
```

I have a table called membership_userrecords which includes the below fields.

You can see the PK value in the table and which user owns it.

I'm just not sure how to do the SQL query.

Can you help?

[image]

Comment: If you don't know what a where clause is then I doubt the login system works right.

Comment: In fact, there is nothing in the above code to suggest that there even is a login system.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm

Comment: Sorry about that - I've added a sample query on the other pages which shows how it works. I'm just not sure how to adapt it to work in this kind of query I've pasted at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I really need to work on my PHP syntax lol. Thanks @aynber

Assuming the username and the memberID are the same, this should be your query.

```
$sql= $conn->prepare("SELECT format(count(*),0) as id12 FROM MarketingCampaigns where memberID = ?");
$sql->bind_param("s", $username);
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($row);
$sql->fetch();

echo $row;
```

I'm really unsure about your data here.

Comment: javascript concatenation uses the plus symbol. PHP uses the period (and a dollar sign on all variable names), but using prepared statements is even better as it prevents SQL injection.

Comment: Sorry about that - I've added a sample query on the other pages which shows how it works. I'm just not sure how to adapt it to work in this kind of query I've pasted at the top